# R parse with bracket

Tags: r

I want to parse the following (i.e initialise this function, the string/parameters of which were created dynamically), but there is a problem with the brackets (Error in parse: unexpected symbol). Is there a way to solve this?

```
parse(text="NAFC_page(label=\"quiet_question\", prompt=\"htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'), choices = \"c(Yes, No)\", \", save_answer = FALSE )")
```

Comment: (1) I suspect `htmltools::HTML` should not be quoted; (2) the Yes/No should be quoted and not the `c(`; and (3) there is what appears to be a random quote-comma before `save_answer=`. Try: `parse(text="NAFC_page(label=\"quiet_question\", prompt=htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'), choices = c(\"Yes\", \"No\"), save_answer = FALSE )")`.

Comment: Where is the prompt supposed to end there? I agree with R, I can't parse that string either.

Comment: Damn it, you were right r2, I changed that in one condition but not the other and was looking in the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the walk-through (in my answer) wasn't necessary, but it illustrated how I found the problems. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `NAFC_page` is, but one way to attack this problem is to replace the `parse` with `cat` and then look at it with code-highlighting (such as using SO's `lang-r` engine).

```r
cat("NAFC_page(label=\"quiet_question\", prompt=\"htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'), choices = \"c(Yes, No)\", \", save_answer = FALSE )", "\n")
```

Since the output this produces is typically a single line requiring horizontal-scrolling, I'm going to interject two newlines to try to keep it all visible in a "normal" browser screen (not necessarily mobile-aware, sorry). This produces:

```r
NAFC_page(label="quiet_question",
 prompt="htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'),
 choices = "c(Yes, No)", ", save_answer = FALSE )
```

Using SO's code highlighting, the first thing that stands out to me is that `htmltools::HTML` is marked as a string. Let's remove the `\"` before it and see what else we see. (`cat`'ed again, just showing the output.)

```r
NAFC_page(label="quiet_question",
 prompt=htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'),
 choices = "c(Yes, No)", ", save_answer = FALSE )
```

Okay, now I see that `\"c(Yes, No)\"` is marked as a string, where I would normally expect it to be a vector `c("Yes", "No")`. Again:

```r
NAFC_page(label="quiet_question",
 prompt=htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'),
 choices = c("Yes", "No"), ", save_answer = FALSE )
```

Now we see that the last argument `save_answer=` (and the rest of the line, in fact) is a string. Let's remove the random quote-comma we see there:

```r
NAFC_page(label="quiet_question",
 prompt=htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'),
 choices = c("Yes", "No"), save_answer = FALSE )
```

That looks much nicer, and likely parses/evaluates better, too.

From here, we should be able to put that back in to your `parse` call:

```r
parse(text="NAFC_page(label=\"quiet_question\", prompt=htmltools::HTML('<p>Are you in a quiet environment?</p>'), choices = c(\"Yes\", \"No\"), save_answer = FALSE )")
```

---

In case the syntax-highlighting portion SO uses changes, here are screenshots for each stage, in order.

[image: syntax-highlighting, stage 1]

[image: syntax-highlighting, stage 2]

[image: syntax-highlighting, stage 3]

[image: syntax-highlighting, stage 4]